# Multi-qubit rotation using Quirk

Tags: quantum-gate, quirk

I was wondering, how can one perform a multi-qubit rotation in Quirk?
For example, if I want to simulate the magic-state distillation protocol, I need e.g. a $(IIZZZ)_{\pi/8}$ rotation of 5 qubits. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I use parity controls combined with global phase gates to achieve this effect.

[Example](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22zpar%22%2C%22zpar%22%2C%22zpar%22%2C%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps3%22%5D%5D%7D)

You can alternatively use phase kickback from controlled Pauli gates to temporarily copy the observable's value onto an ancilla, and then phase the ancilla with a Z,S,T,etc gate.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I understand your example correctly, you did a ZZZ rotation of the first 3 qubits, whereas the last one used for the global phase but is not part of the calculation? This is to say, for the magic state distillation with 5 qubits rotations, I need to use an additional one with this sqrt(i) in each rotation?

Comment: @DavidDentelski that's right. It's not really involved; just there as a place to park the label.